# javascript regex to exclude a string in test

Tags: javascript, regex

This javascript regex tries to match "good job" or "good game" but not "good boy"
Any idea how to get it to work by returning false for "good boy"? thx

```js
let strArr = ['good job', 'good game', 'good boy'];

for (i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
let res= /good[jobgame]*|good(?= boy)/ig.test(strArr[i])
console.log(res)
}
```

Comment: Just use: `/\bgood (?:job|game)\b/g`

Comment: FYI: It is not a good idea to use `g` modifier with a regex passed to `RegExp#test()`. `/\bgood (?:job|game)\b/` will do. Unless the `good` can start with a non-word char, or `job/game` can end with a non-word char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to match 'good job' or 'good game'.

```js
let strArr = ['good job', 'good game', 'good boy'];

for (i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
let res= /good (job|game)/ig.test(strArr[i])
console.log(res)
}
```

Or you could directly do a negative look-ahead to not match good boy:

```js
    let strArr = ['good job', 'good game', 'good boy'];

    for (i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    let res= /good (?!boy)/ig.test(strArr[i])
    console.log(res)
    }
```

Comment: This is good. See my answer about anchors though. Maybe `/\bgood (job|game)\b/` would be better. Also note what Wiktor commented to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
let res= /good(?! boy)/ig.test(strArr[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to limit it to "job" and "game". Otherwise the second half of your own attempt  **almost** does it. Turn it to a negative look-ahead, instead of a positive one:

```
good(?! boy)
```

will match good followed by anything **but** boy.

Then again... It could be polished somewhat

```
\bgood\s(?!boy\b)\w+
```

matches the word `good` followed by another word that isn't boy.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tl7DjS/4).

Or to only allow the two words on a line, add start/end anchors:

```
^good\s(?!boy\b)\w+$
```

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tl7DjS/5).